# ¿Cómo cargar imagen desde la galeria con Picasso?

Tags: android, android-studio, picasso

Estoy intentando cargar en un ImageView una foto desde la galeria, para ello estoy utilizando la libreria picasso de Android.

Con este codigo accedo a la galeria:

```
btnGallery = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGallery);

        btnGallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(intent, PICTURE_FROM_GALLERY);
            }
        });
```

Y con este debería de recibir la imagen de la galeria:

```
    case PICTURE_FROM_GALLERY:
                    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        Uri path = data.getData();
                        File imageFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(path));
                        Picasso.with(AddClothesActivity.this).load(imageFile).into(photoGallery);

                    }
```

y el metodo que obtiene el path es :

```
 private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI) {
        String result;
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null) { // Source is Dropbox or other similar local file path
            result = contentURI.getPath();
        } else {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
            result = cursor.getString(idx);
            cursor.close();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Pero me da fallo y se cierra la aplicacion.

Debuggeando he observado que me da el path correcto pero no lo carga en photoGallery, photoGallery: null

Comment: Recuerda que siempre es recomendable agregar lo que muestra el LogCat en el caso de Android, esto para evitar perder mucho tiempo en resolver un problema que puede ser sencillo de solucionar.

Comment: Que es photoGallery? comparte por favor todo el codigo para ver como estas recuperando el elemento donde quieres desplegar la vista.

Comment: photoGallery seria una ImageView

Answer (score -1):

En el caso de `Picasso` si la url o el archivo que deseas cargar no contiene valor o tiene valor null, esto provocará un error, así que tienes que validar para evitar un problema en tu aplicación

```
File imageFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(path));
if(imageFile != null){                        
   Picasso.with(AddClothesActivity.this).load(imageFile).into(photoGallery);
}
```

---

Te recomiendo asegurar que recibes en realidad estas recibiendo la Uri :

```
   Uri path = data.getData(); //* ???
   File imageFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(path));
```

Comment: **Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.